# How to clean and brighten reflective wall tires

Tags: tire, winter, cleaning

I have a set of Continental Touring tires with the white reflective stripe on the sidewalls, and they get pretty dirty with road and brake grime.  Normally I would clean with car soap and water but sometimes it doesn't get all the dirt off/make them look new.  It is also winter right now so it is harder to soap and water wash in the garage.  I did use a washcloth and clear water from bucket. It helped a lot but still a long ways off.  Is there a way that I can make the stripe clean and bright white again?

NOTE:  The reflective strip on these tires are a tape that is added to the tire.  I have another bike with different brand tires where they might be painted on.

Comment: I think they always dull out. You can buy 3m Scotchlite tape and add it to your frame for side reflectivity or apply a coat of reflective paint to the sidewalls, but I don't think anything will restore it properly.

Comment: Go to a place that sells auto soaps and polishes and buy some tire cleaner.

Comment: (Though one wonders who worries about cleaning the sides of their tires.)

Comment: Mine are Schwalbe rather than continental but while they don't look perfect after a normal soap & water wash with a bit of a brush they're almost as reflective as new after 3000 miles of commuting. I have been known to use a pressure house on my rims and tyres only but there's no real benefit to it and keeping the high pressure spray away from the bearings means it's more hassle than it's worth.

Comment: @DanielRHicks - some automotive tire cleaners are acidic, non-acidic ones still use powerful detergents, and many are not meant for use on uncoated aluminum (like many bike wheels). I would be afraid that an automotive tire cleaner would clean the thin reflective coating right off the tire. To your point about why clean sidewalls, I don't think he's cleaning his sidewalls to make them look spiffy and clean, he's trying to make his reflective sidewalls more visible for winter riding.

Comment: @Johnny I'm trying to do both really.  The strip is wide enough to give the tires a nice white wall look without looking like dinner plates.  I just cleaned it because the grime was getting unsightly.  They still reflected just fine though, I have a few brag photos to show for that.

Comment: I added a note in the question pointing out an observation I have made about the reflective strip.  It looks like for these tires it is some kind of tape maybe?  I found the application start and stop point.  The end of it overlaps the start and has peeled back some.  Looks like it doesn't stick well to itself.

Comment: Soapy water with the rough side of a kitchen sponge did wonders for my tires. Didn't even know they had a reflective stripe before I cleaned them ...

Comment: Tape added during the manufacturing process does mean it is something that can be reapplied in the field. You observed it does not even stick to itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hit the tires with a bush and some concentrated soap.
In the dark shine a light on them and you would be surprised how much they shine even if they look dirty.
Once you scuff em up bad then just time for new tires.

Comment: I ended up using dish soap for this and a old wash cloth.  It takes a little bit of scrubbing but the results are acceptable.  Not bright white like new, but I have white stripe tires again when done.